# Adding group column to data frame

Tags: r

Say I have the following data frame:

```
dx=data.frame(id=letters[1:4], count=1:4)

#   id count
# 1  a     1
# 2  b     2
# 3  c     3
# 4  d     4
```

And I would like to (grammatically) add a column that will get the count whenever `count`<3, otherwise 3, so I'll get the following:

```
#   id count group
# 1  a     1     1
# 2  b     2     2
# 3  c     3     3
# 4  d     4     3
```

I thought to use

```
dx$group=if(dx$count<3){dx$count}else{3}
```

but it doesn't work on arrays. How can I do it?

Comment: `df$group <- pmin(df$count, 3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you can just use `pmin` (as I stated in the comments above):

```
df$group <- pmin(df$count, 3)
```

In general your if/else construction does not work on vectors, but you can use the function `ifelse`. It takes three arguments: First the condition, then the result if the condition is met and finally the result if the condition is not met. For your example you would write the following:

```
df$group <- ifelse(df$count < 3, df$count, 3)
```

Note that in your example the `pmin` solution is better. Just mentioning the `ifelse` solution for completeness.